# what function has this property under optimization?

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, nonlinear-optimization

I have a function $f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$. Here $x_i $ are real variables and $f$ is also real. I tried such a method for finding the minimum of $f$.

First, let us fix $x_2$ to $x_n$, and find the $x_1$ that minimizes $f$. Then, let us fix all $x_i$ other than $x_2$, and find the $x_2$ that minimizes $f$. Next we turn to $x_3$, and so on.

It is observed that $f$ decays in a power law way (very slow) towards the minimum.

The question is, what kind of function has this behavior? In my case, the function $f$ has no explicit expression, it is like a black box.

It is not hard to see that if $f$ is a quadratic function, then it will decay exponentially towards the minimum.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean. First, by your minimization process. Do you mean that you find the function $x_1(x_2, \dots, x_n)$ such that $f(x_1(x_2, \dots x_n), x_2, \dots, x_n)$ is minimized, then find the function $x_2(x_3, \dots, x_n)$ such that $f(x_1(x_2(x_3,\dots,x_n), x_3, \dots, x_n), x_2(x_3,\dots,x_n), x_3, \dots, x_n)$ is minimized, etc.? Then when you say "$f$ decays" - with respect to what variables is it decaying? And where are those variables approaching during this decay?

Comment: This is exactly what I mean. $f$ decays as a function of the number of iteration.

Comment: You don't discuss "iteration" in your question, so again what do you mean by that?

Comment: Every time you update one variable is an iteration.